# mvn maven-thucydides-plugin JAR access denied

Tags: windows, selenium, jar, maven-3, thucydides

I was working correctly with Selenium + Thucydides, but for some reason I got this error now when I am running clean install skipping tests.

> [WARNING] error reading
>   C:\path.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-server\2.43.1\selenium-server-2.43.1.jar;
>   C:\path.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-server\2.43.1
>   \selenium-server-2.43.1.jar (Access is denied)
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   net.thucydides.maven.plugins:maven-thucydides-plugin:0.9.268:aggregate
>   (thucydides-reports) on project mdpubgui: Execution thucydides-reports
>   of goal net.thucydides.maven.plugins:maven-thucydides-
>   plugin:0.9.268:aggregate failed: Could not read from the JAR file:

Is like the plugin is not able to access to the jar, but the jar is correctly located in the repository, and was working few days ago.

Maybe is because of some O.S update? Any clue is really appreciated

Windows 10
Maven 3
Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally seems the problem was a restriction from the OS, I changed the M2 settings and move the repository to another location in the computer, then everything started to work again, so for some reason the JAR file was locked.